# Tiagra 9 speed triple front with a 10 speed group

Tags: compatibility

I want to temporarily swap parts on two bikes for a trip - I currently have a Tiagra 9-speed setup and a bike with Ultegra 6600 double/10 speed. Is it possible to use the triple front shifter from a 9-speed group with the Ultegra group (substituting an Ultegra triple crank and FD that I'd buy) ?

Comment: I posed a similar question a while ago, any use? http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13294/upgrade-shimano-from-9-to-10-speed

Comment: @PeteH - I need to know specifically about the derailuer and the gruppo.  It 'should' work, but 'should' is never certain with this sort of stuff....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work, but you need to double check shifting range settings — stops — on the front derailleur.

I recommend use second and third positions of shifter for inner and outer rings respectively (not the first and second).

If you will use not only triple front shifter but also a triple front derailleur you must consider that shifting on double crankset with triple derailleur wouldn't be as fine as with double derailleur (because of triple derailleur frame form).

Comment: sorry, what is a "triple derailleur frame form"?

Comment: Each front derailleur has a «frame» part which guide the chain from one chainring to another. Form of this part isn't similar for 2-speed and 3-speed derailleurs.

Comment: Oh I see, this helped too: http://sheldonbrown.com/images/frontderailers23.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It will work OK. I've used an 8 speed mountain bike derailleur with a 10 speed group on my cross bike. It won't be the crispest, but it will work. Just adjust the limiter screws until it shifts appropriately.

Comment: Swapping rear derailleurs within a manufacturer with different speeds or between mountain and road typically isn't really a problem for the most part- they don't really care what goes on between the limit stops (you just need to have sufficiently long cages typically, as the cable pull is usually the same except with systems like dynasys). A lot of touring bikes for example are often spec'd with a Deore rear and STI/bar end shifters. Fronts on the other hand are road/mountain specific even wtihin a manufacturer.